# Why my question was marked as duplicated?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicate-questions, reopen-closed

I wrote [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64832158/how-to-find-all-the-classes-of-a-package-in-java-9-and-later) that was marked as duplicated: could someone explain to me the reason since the post that was indicated to me as original does not solve my problem on java 9 and later?

Comment: Accidental dupe. I reopened the post. If you think this means someone is obligated to solve your problem, you're wrong. If you want to contribute to the quality of the site, solve (or at least try solving) your problem and answer your own question. You'll get upvotes and points (as I'm sure other people would like to use Reflections lib on Java 9+). Otherwise this is just "I want free help and I'm not getting it, please do something!".

Comment: The irony of this very post being closed as a duplicate.

Comment: 90% of the questions asked on Meta are duplicates, @Federico. We've been at this a *long* time; most of the issues that can possibly be encountered have already been encountered and discussed at length. Sometimes, though, it takes a special talent to be able to *find* those duplicates. :-)

Comment: Not to mention that from times to times, the duplicate is on meta SE. Sometimes I wish we could duplicate close cross-communities.

Comment: @Kayaman why did not you edit the question to clarify that half a dozen answers in the suggested duplicate did not resolve the issue? The question had to be closed again till you finish the edit...

Answer (score 1):

Members of the community voted to close your question as a duplicate of an existing question, which they thought provided a solution to your problem.

The person who originally suggested the duplicate posted in the comments that Reflections *does* support Java 9, refuting your claim that it did not.

It is, of course, possible that they were mistaken. If you still believe that your question is not a duplicate of the proposed question, you should edit it to clarify the differences and provide evidence that a viable solution could not be found there.

Comment: in the comment it says that reflection works with java 9, not the library linked to by OP, which is called reflection**s**.

Comment: Your moderation policy should definitely be revised as it is absolutely clear that it is not a duplicate question

Comment: @LukeS as soon as your membership fee comes in, we the voluntary moderators will use that money to discuss the policies. How much did you pay for StackOverflow again? /s

Comment: By this way the site will be filled with posts with old and broken examples

Comment: @LukeS while it may not be a duplicate of that question, it's still a question you should ask the maintainers of the reflections library. you asked what could be done, the answer is "use the standard reflection mechanisms from java", which is what the duplicate target explains.